# How to update selected rows in a data.table if they match value from another data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I would like to find a data.table solution for updating selected rows from values in another table:

Table 1 looks like this

```
id  var grade
1   var1    X
2   var2    B
3   var3    X
4   var4    D
5   var5    X
```

Table 2

```
id  var grade
1   var1    Y
2   var2    B2
3   var3    Y
4   var4    D2
5   var5    Y
```

the updated table 1 looks like this

```
id  var grade
1   var1    Y
2   var2    B
3   var3    Y
4   var4    D
5   var5    Y
```

any help is much appreciated

Comment: What is the logic?

Comment: What is the criteria that has to be satisfied for a value to be updated? Only containing letters? Only being one character? etc.

Answer (score 2):

We can just use second dataset and remove the digits at the end

```
 df2$grade <- sub("\\d+$", "", df2$grade)
```

---

Or in `data.table`, convert the first data.frame to 'data.table', and assign 'grade' with the second datasets 'grade' joined by 'id', 'var' and remove the digits at the end

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[df2, grade := i.grade, on = .(id, var)][, grade := sub("\\d+$", "", grade][]
```

Or as @IceCreamToucan commented

```
setDT(df1)[df2, grade := sub("\\d+$", "", i.grade), on = .(id, var)]
```